# Git log stats with regular expressions

Tags: regex, git, bash, git-log

I would like to do some stats on my git log to get something like:

```
10 Daniel Schmidt
5  Peter
1  Klaus
```

The first column is the count of commits and the second the commiter.
I already got as far as this:

```
    git log --raw |
    grep "^Author: " |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    sort -nr |
    less -FXRS
```

The interesting part is the

```
    grep "^Author: "
```

which i wanted to modify with a nice Regex to exclude the mail adress.
With Rubular something like this http://rubular.com/r/mEzP2hFjGb worked, but if i insert it in the grep (or in a piped other one) it won't get me the right output.

Sidequestion: Is there a possibility to get the count and the author seperated by something else then whitespace while staying in this pipe command style? I would like to have a nicer seperator between both to us column later (and maybe some color ^^)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Any particular reason you're piping `log` to `grep` instead of just using `git shortlog -n -s`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google `git-extras`. It has a `git summary` that does this.

Answer (score 1):

`git shortlog -n -s` gets you the same data. On the git repository, for example (piped to head to get higher numbers):

```
$ git shortlog -n -s | head -4
 11129  Junio C Hamano
  1395  Shawn O. Pearce
  1103  Linus Torvalds
   896  Jeff King
```

To get a different delimiter, you could pipe it to `awk`:

```
$ git shortlog -n -s | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|";} { $1=$1; print $0 }' | head -4
 11129|Junio|C|Hamano
  1395|Shawn|O.|Pearce
  1103|Linus|Torvalds
   896|Jeff|King
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full power of pcre (which should match your experiments with Rebular) with a perl one-liner:

```
perl -ane 'print if /^Author: /'
```

Just extend that pattern as necessary.

To reformat you can use `awk` (eg `awk '{printf "%5d\t%s", $1, $2}'`)